# Jquery mobile R&D - how to customise the CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

We are running a (desktop) e-commerce site which is pretty large (in terms of coding and different sections), on the Zend Framework. We are now planning a mobile-optimised website, and we are researching into Jquery Mobile.

We are trying two things to decide which path we should choose.

1) Using a Jquery mobile theme to build our HTML, and then customise it from there.

OR

2) Build our own theme.

At the moment I'm experimenting with 2) building our own theme.

I found issues on customizing the pages (CSS). Please could you answer my following questions. I'm following the guide on the Jquery mobile site.

1) Is it mandatory to inlclude default jquery css (http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css)?

OR

2) Is it possible to update the default jquery css with our custom styles?

Another issue, I've created the file using the below code,

```
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-corners="false" data-theme="inner_menu">

            <h3 class="inner_menu_heading">Section A1</h3>



            <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-corners="false">

                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">

                    <h3 class="sub_menu_heading">Section A1.1</h3>

                    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>

                </div>



                <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">

                    <h3 class="sub_menu_heading">Section A1.2</h3>

                    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>

                </div>

            </div>

        <!-- section A1 end here-->

        </div>
```

However after the page loads, it's giving additional tags. Please see the code below.

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content" aria-hidden="false">

    <div data-corners="false" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="arrow-r" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible-set" class="ui-collapsible-set">

                    <div data-collapsed="false" data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed">

                        <h3 class="sub_menu_heading ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed ui-li-heading">

                        <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">

                        <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Section A1.1<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></span>

                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-plus">&nbsp;</span></span></a></h3>

                        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">

                            <p class="ui-li-desc">I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>



                    <div data-collapsed="false" data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed">

                        <h3 class="sub_menu_heading ui-collapsible-heading ui-li-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">

                        <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-focus ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">

                        <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Section A1.2<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></span>

                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-plus">&nbsp;</span></span></a></h3>

                        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">

                            <p class="ui-li-desc">I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

<!-- section A1 end here-->

</div>
```

These additonal tags (such as the new  and  tags after the ) are causing style issues. Is it possible to remove / customize these tags in order to avoid issues?

OR

since I need to include the jquery.min CSS file, shall I just keep the jquery default CSS files and create an override CSS file for customization?

OR

shall I make my OWN CSS file, copy the normal jquery CSS and then change it on my own? Therefore I have one CSS file total.

Please Help/advise me to solve the above problem.

Comment: I think you need to research *better* into jQuery Mobile and its themes customization

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain some of the facts I know about using customised jquery mobile css.

1.When you are using jquery to customise your page it will try to redesign your entire markup in its own format,e.g: adding your entire content in a "page" role tag if you haven't added one.Also it will add additional tags for styling the elements.This is because it converts the "data-role" attribute to stylised markup and thats not a problem.

2.If you are building your own custom theme from jquery theme roller,you should note that it will roll out a css with new swatches designed by you.If you want to style your elements with your customised theme only,then using jquery-mobile.css is optional.If you want to use themes from jquery css and also add your own new theme ,then create a new swatch with theme="f" or later since themes "a" to "e" are already predefined in jquery mobile css.Using your new theme in combination with jquery mobile css will need to modify the jquery css i.e. just taking your new styles and pasting them into jquery css.This wont be difficult because you new styles will be made with the swatch letters,like ui-bar-f,ui-body-f,ui-button-up-f,etc....

I reckon you should take a look at jquery mobile docs too.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation on how to customize JQM themes. Check [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-custom-theme-jquery-mobile) out